# open an existing sqlite database - HTML5

Tags: database, html, sqlite

I am trying to access an sqlite3 DB from an HTML5 page. The DB is found the physical folder. How to open the DB. All the sample in net describes window.openDatabase() method. This is creating a new db instance. How to open an existing database.

thanks in advance

Geervani

Comment: HTML can read databases now? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you tried to use "window.openDatabase()" on an existing database, what happens to the data?

My guess is "window.openDatabase()":

- creates the DB is not existent,
- then use it use it if it exists

Comment: Yeah even i thought the same, but its not reading the data from the existing tables. Its showing 0 records.